# Regular Expression only numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out a regular expression to extract the numbers from a string. At the moment I have the string:

```
USD0,13
```

I'd like to search for only the `0,13`.

There will be other strings that will contain numbers such as `USD1,14` for example.

Any help would be great.
Cheers

Comment: What have you tried? What regex engine are you using? Look up character classes.

Comment: [Tutorial on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: As this is regex, it will only be a matter of time until someone answers this question anyway :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest one for your case would be this:

```
'/[0-9,]+/'
```

In PHP

```
$str = 'USD0,13';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/[0-9,]+/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex of `/USD([0-9,\.]+)/` should do what you want. The dot is not necessarily needed unless you have thousand seperators (considering it looks like you're using EU standards).

If you want multiple currencies, you could do this: `/(EUR|GBP|USD)([0-9\,\.]+)/`.

Since you seem pretty new to Regex, I'll explain:

`/` is the modifier of the Regex (this can be anything, but we'll use a slash which is the most common character for regexes). If you want it to be incase-sensitive, you can for example do `/regex/i` and `i` would mean incase-sensitive.

`USD` is just a character list of `U` followed by `S` followed by `D`.

`(` and `)` means that we want the regex to output this match to us.

`[0-9,\.]` means numbers from `0` to `9`, commas and dots (note that the dot has to be escaped, as `.` in regex means "any character".)

Our match is followed by a `+`  which means "anything that matches this match, repeated 1 or more times".

The second example we've switched `USD` out with `(EUR|GBP|USD)`. This means "EUR" or "GBP" or "USD".

If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.